# How to install Selenium with Java on new system and to use Jenkins as CI to generate proper test report

Tags: java, svn, selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm going to start Automation in my current project. I want to set up Selenium for Test Automation using Java. I want Jenkins (formerly known as Hudson) to provide proper Test Report. How to install and configure Jenkins/Hudson with Selenium? I want to commit and update my script through SVN, So how to link up with Selenium test cases in SVN with Jenkins?

Can you give me easy and very clear picture and steps in proper format?

Comment: Hudson doesn't exist any more. It was renamed to [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Answer (score 1):

First create a Selenium enabled project in Java. I recommend using maven as it simplifies few things. Simply write a few tests using these tools. 
This may be helpful:
http://www.theserverlabs.com/blog/2008/09/17/automated-integration-testing-with-selenium-maven-and-jetty/

Don't mind Jetty - it's just an application server utility.

Having done this initial phase you can simply configure jenkins' (Hudson) new job to browse repo for your Selenium test project. Running it from Jenkins will perform tests.

Jenkins will automatically generate basic reports, you can also use other tools like Thucydides and Easyb that will support test creation and report generation.